# CSES - Distinct Colors

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, depth-first-search

I was trying to solve a question on [cses - Distinct Colors](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1139/), My solution based on the book [Competitive Programmer’s Handbook by Antti Laaksonen](https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf) **page number 170(Merging data structures)**

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int Mxn = 2e5;
unordered_set<int> adj[Mxn],mp[Mxn];
int c[Mxn],ans[Mxn],n;
 
void dfs(int u=0, int p = -1){
    for(auto v: adj[u]){
        if(v != p){
            dfs(v,u);
            if(mp[v].size() > mp[u].size())
                swap(mp[v],mp[u]);
            mp[u].insert(mp[v].begin(),mp[v].end());
        }
    }
    mp[u].insert(c[u]);
    ans[u] = mp[u].size();
}
 
int main(){
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cin>>c[i];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        int x,y; cin>>x>>y; x--,y--;
        adj[x].insert(y);
        adj[y].insert(x);
    }
    dfs();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) cout<<ans[i]<<' ';
}
```

What I want to know is that when I swap the two maps in the above code using

```cpp
if(mp[v].size() > mp[u].size())
    swap(mp[v],mp[u]);
```

The code gets **Accepted**, but when I **do not swap** these maps I get a **TLE**, here is a quote from the book :

> The merging of nodes can be done as follows: We go through the children of *s* and at each child *u* merge d[*s*] and d[*u*]. We always copy the contents from d[*u*] to d[*s*]. However, before this, we swap the contents of d[*s*] and d[*u*] if d[*s*] is smaller than d[*u*]. By doing this, each value is copied only *O(log(n))* times during the tree traversal, which ensures that the algorithm is efficient.

how does swapping the maps according to their size ensures that each element would be at most copied *O(log(N))* times?

If all the colors are unique, then the complexity to copy one map to another would-be *O(N)* right? That would make total complexity *O(N^2)*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this algorithm is known as "small-to-large merging". The main idea is that each vertex will be merged at most `log(N)` times.

First, the swap condition ensures that the smaller set will merge into the larger set. Thus, every time some vertex `v` is merged, the new set containing `v` will be at least double the size of the original set containing `v`. We can imagine that the size of the sets containing `v` after every merge will look something like this: `1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 8 ... -> N`.

Since each vertex will be merged at most `log(N)` times, the number of merges for all vertices is `N log(N)`. The final complexity is `O(N log N)`.